# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null, react-fullpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fullpage.js

```
   <div className="left">
  <ReactFullpage
      licenseKey='xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx'
      sectionsColor={["#000000"]}
      render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
          return (
              <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
              {this.state.items == undefined ? '' : this.state.items.map((img,i) => (
                <img className="section" key={i} src={img.image}></img>
            ))}
              </div>
          );
      }}
  />

  </div>
```

Hi, I've some issues when I am trying to fetch the data and render in ReactFullpage Component, the error says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Thank you, all help is welcome.

Comment: But i use a component, if i render the component without fetch it works.

Comment: Please check whether this.state.items has any values inside it or not. It might be the case that, your component is getting mounted before the state getting updated. Would be great if you post the code where you update/set your state

Comment: `loadimage(a){
  fetch("http://****.***/"+a)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        items: result,
      });
    },

    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        loaded:''
      });
    }
  )
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that ReactFullPage works on the principle of finding a className section in one of the rendered elements

Now since you load your items async, initially the following content is rendered

```
    return (
          <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
          {''}
          </div>
      );
```

Notice that it doesn't have a className section to it and it throws you the error

The solution here is to either wait for items to load before showing ReactFullPage

```
    <div className="left">
      {this.state.items && <ReactFullpage
          licenseKey='xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx'
          sectionsColor={["#000000"]}
          render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
              return (
                  <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
                  {this.state.items.map((img,i) => (
                    <img className="section" key={i} src={img.image}></img>
                  )}
                  </div>
              );
          }}
      />}
   </div>
```

or return a dummy component to ReactFullPage

```
<div className="left">
  <ReactFullpage
      licenseKey='xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx'
      sectionsColor={["#000000"]}
      render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
          return (
              <div id="fullpage-wrapper">
              {this.state.items == undefined ? <div className="section" /> : this.state.items.map((img,i) => (
                <img className="section" key={i} src={img.image}></img>
            ))}
              </div>
          );
      }}
  />
</div>
```